# How can I save a visual change a user made to my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making a web page where users can press buttons to add elements using `appendChild` but when they refresh the page it all goes away. Is there something I can do to save what the users add to the page so that when they refresh it it stays the same?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="write anything here...">
<button id="submit" onclick="createEl()">Submit</button>
<div class="text-div" id="text-div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#submit {
  height: 55px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var txtDiv = document.getElementById("text-div")
var inputField = document.getElementById("input")

function createEl() {
   if (inputField.value !== "") {
      var p = document.createElement("p")
      var pNode = document.createTextNode(inputField.value)
      p.appendChild(pNode)
      txtDiv.appendChild(p)
}
}
```

Comment: You must use a database to save all your new elements, and load every time when the page was opened

Comment: If the changes only need to be kept in a single browser (not when logging in from another one), you can use localStorage or cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as people said earlier the if you want to load your data in all browsers regardless of where did those data came from, you should set up a database, based on your need and specification. Otherwise, **you can get used to existing stuff in browsers such as [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**. So you need to create a property in it, then on each page reload check whether there are data saved there or not with [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var txtDiv = document.getElementById("text-div")
var inputField = document.getElementById("input")
var items = [];

function createItem(item) {
  var p = document.createElement("p")
  var pNode = document.createTextNode(item)
  p.appendChild(pNode)
  txtDiv.appendChild(p)
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem("items") !== null) {
    items = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("items"))
    var itemsLength = items.length

    for (var i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
      createItem(items[i])
    }
  }
}

function createEl() {
  if (inputField.value !== "") {
    createItem(inputField.value)
    items.push(inputField.value)
    window.localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a database, you could try storing their progress within window.localStorage. On page load, you would need to run a function that checks for this item; if present, the function would then repopulate all of their information. After each submission, you would also need to update local storage so that their progress stays current.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some method of persistent storage. If you don't care about saving the changes forever, then you can save user changes in `localStorage`. If you need to make sure the changes will always be available, then you'll need to create a database and handle saving and loading data from an API that connects to it.

Here's an example of how to do this using `localStorage`:

```
    var txtDiv = document.getElementById("text-div")
    var inputField = document.getElementById("input")

    const getSaved = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saved"));

    function saveEl(val) {
        const saved = getSaved();
        let newInputArr = saved ? [...saved, val] : [val];
        localStorage.setItem("saved", JSON.stringify(newInputArr));
    }

    function createEl(val) {
        var p = document.createElement("p")
        var pNode = document.createTextNode(val)
        p.appendChild(pNode)
        txtDiv.appendChild(p)
    }

    function saveAndCreate() {
        if((inputField.value !== "")) {
            saveEl(inputField.value);
            createEl(inputField.value);
        }
    }

    const saved = getSaved();
    if(saved && saved.length) {
        saved.forEach((val) => {
            createEl(val)
        })
    }
```